# Compiler error "illegal start of expression"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I tried to compile my `Card` class for a video poker assignment. I got the `illegal start of expression` compiler error. I'm pretty sure the two methods it points to are written correctly--they are just simple getter methods. So it must be something else I fail to notice. Please help. Thanks.

`public class Card` implements `Comparable<Card>`{

```
private int suit; 
private int value; 

public Card(int s, int v)
{ //constructor of an object Card
    s = suit;
    v = value;
    //make a card with suit s and value v
}

public int compareTo(Card c)
{
    if(this.value > c.value)
    { 
        return 1;
    }
    if(this.value < c.value)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}       

    // use this method to compare cards so they 
    // may be easily sorted



public String toString() //to tell the user what card/s they have
{
    //for printing?//
//  ArrayList<String> forPrint = new ArrayList<String>();
    getHand();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        hand.get(i).getSuit();
        hand.get(i).getValue();
        if(s == 1)
        {
            if(v == 11)
            {
                return "Jack of Clubs";
            //  forPrint.add("Jack of Clubs");
            }
            if(v == 12)
            {
                return "Queen of Clubs";
            //  forPrint.add("Queen of Clubs"); 
            }
            if(v == 13)
            {
                return "King of Clubs";
            //  forPrint.add("King of Clubs");  
            }
            if(v == 1)
            {
                return "Ace of Clubs";
            //  forPrint.add("Ace of Clubs")    
            }
            else
            {
                return v + " of Clubs";
            //  forPrint.add(v + " of Clubs");
            }   
        }
        if(s == 2)
        {
            if(v == 11)
            {
                return "Jack of Diamonds";
            //  forPrint.add("Jack of Diamonds");   
            }
            if(v == 12)
            {
                return "Queen of Diamonds";
            //  forPrint.add("Queen of Diamonds");  
            }
            if(v == 13)
            {
                return "King of Diamonds";
            //  forPrint.add("KIng of Diamonds");   
            }
            if(v == 1)
            {
                return "Ace of Diamonds";
            //  forPrint.add("Ace of Diamonds");    
            }
            else{
                return v + "of Diamonds";
            //  forPrint.add(v + " of Diamonds")    
        }
        if(s == 3)
        {
            if(v == 11)
            {
                return "Jack of Hearts";
            }
            if(v == 12)
            {
                return "Queen of Hearts";
            }
            if(v == 13)
            {
                return "King of Hearts";
            }
            if(v == 1)
            {
                return "Ace of Hearts";
            }
            else
            {
                return v + "of Hearts";
            }
        }
        if(s == 4)
        {
            if(v == 11)
            {
                return "Jack of Spades";
            }
            if(v == 12)
            {
                return "Queen of Spades";
            }
            if(v == 13)
            {
                return "King of Spades";
            }
            if(v == 1)
            {
                return "Ace of Spades";
            }
            else
            {
                return v + "of Spades";
            }
        }

    }
}
//DB method to set 1, 2, 3, and 4 to card suits


//now here create string representation for the Card    
    // use this method to easily print a Card object

public int getSuit()
{
    return s;
}
public int getValue()
{
    return v;
}   

//DB right now have cards in theDeck like Card(2, 10), need Card(d, 10)
//need to convert that to a String d10 

// add some more methods here if needed

}
```

This is the compile errors I get:

```
$ javac Card.java
Card.java:149: illegal start of expression
    public int getSuit()
    ^
Card.java:149: ';' expected
    public int getSuit()
                      ^
Card.java:153: illegal start of expression
    public int getValue()
    ^
Card.java:153: ';' expected
    public int getValue()
                       ^
Card.java:163: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
5 errors
```

Comment: Go carefully through each line, specially curly braces `{}` and verify that they match.

Comment: And then try to solve many other compilation errors too..

Comment: Make sure to fix your constructor too. Should be suit = s and value = v.

Comment: Your getter methods should return `suit` and `value` and not `s` and `v`. Also inside constructors it should have been `suit=s;` and `value=v;`.

Comment: The constructor was given to us by the instructor. It cannot be modified...

Answer (score 2):

For starters,

Missing a `}`

```
    else {
       return v + "of Diamonds";
       ...
```

Comment: Note that there are a lot more errors in the program.

Comment: Ah how could I miss that. Thanks!